# How to use foreign key when querying from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My question is quite basic. 
It is about how can i build my query with using a foreign key to select certain information from two tables?

```
table vehicles
+-------+----------+------------+
| id_car| car_model| car_owner  |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  1    |       VW |         132|
+-------+----------+------------+
|  2    |       VW |         200|
+-------+----------+------------+
table users
+-------+----------+------------+
|user_id| user_name| user_phone |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  132  |     Peter|    555-555 |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  200  |      Jim |    555-333 |
+-------+----------+------------+
```

`car_owner` is foreign key in `vehicles` table which references to the primary key `user_id` of `users` table.

So someone is searching for all VW cars and i want to have as populate the following information as html(yes, I know that this is not the correct way - i use this just to simplify the example and show which information from each table goes):

```
>    echo "Car model:". `vehicles.car_model`
>    echo "Car owner:". `users.user_name`
>    echo "Contacts: ". `users.user_phone`
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure, if you understood what foreign keys are used for. A foreign key basically says "for this entry there has to be an entry in the parent table". You said `user_id is foreign key in vehicle table`, which is not clear for me.

So, let's assume you have a table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles
(`id_car` int, `car_model` varchar(2), `car_owner` int);


CREATE TABLE users
(`user_id` int, `user_name` varchar(5), `user_phone` varchar(7)
, CONSTRAINT `fk_your_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES vehicles(car_owner)
);
```

When you want to insert a new user into the table, the user_id must be an existing entry in car_owner column in vehicles table.

Foreign keys are there to implement business rules. Does every user necessarily have to be a car owner? Or the other way round, does every car have to be owned by someone? If you can answer both questions with no, then don't implement any foreign keys for this case. But do so, if you can answer yes for sure.

To get the information you're looking for just do

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
vehicles 
INNER JOIN users ON vehicles.car_owner = users.user_id
```

Comment: Hi tombom. Sorry for the misleading introduction. I have made some amendments in the text and the table. I'm getting the point of the foreign keys and 'yes' are the answers of your last question. What i was missing was the JOIN thing. Now thing are much clearer to me. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

from a learner's perspective, it is striking that the foreign keys don't appear to be functional wrt linking tables in queries: i.e. the queries given in the 3 answers above work w/o foreign keys.
e.g. for the last example, a mysql learner would expect mysql to implicitly infer from a foreign key that vehicle.car_owner = user.users_id so that when querying

```
SELECT vehicles.car_model, users.user_name, users.user_phone
FROM vehicles JOIN users
```

should suffice. While the query code :

```
 ON vehicles.car_owner = users.users_id
```

looks like redundant explicit re-statement of the foreign key

Comment: Precisely! The FK is just for referential integrity. Your "from vehicles join users" clause is really all that should be necessary, until there are multiple FKs, such as "car_owner", "primary_driver", so instead of specifying the table, specify the foreign key, such as "FROM vehicles JOIN car_owner'. But - the users table has a foreign key ...

Answer (score 2):

Use JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles INNER JOIN users ON (vehicles.car_owner=users.user_id)
```

To expand: `vehicles INNER JOIN users` will return only cars that have owners. If you want to display cars that have a NULL for owner, or a deleted owner, then use `vehicles LEFT JOIN users`.

For `vehicles INNER JOIN users` there is also a different way possible:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles, users WHERE vehicles.car_owner=users.user_id
```

The latter selects rows matching the condition from the cartesian product of the two tables.

Comment: There should not be a difference. To check this put EXPLAIN in front of the queries.

Answer (score 2):

You need SQL Join, something like this -

```
SELECT vehicles.car_model, users.user_name, users.user_phone
FROM vehicles
JOIN users ON vehicles.car_owner = users.users_id
```