# Codeigniter : insert multiply data in the same column

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I'm working on an exam system. Each exam has a page with multiple questions and multiple choices.

This is my table :

```
id
exam_title
question
choice1
choice2
choice3
response
W
R
date_ex
```

I want it to be like this. The question column should have multiple questions. Each question will have choices in a single column, say, choices.
Is this possible ? If not, what are the possible ways ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different table for choices and map it to the questions table by question id. For example:

```
Question     Choice

id           question_id (FK of question table)
exam_title   choice
question
response
W
R
date_ex
```

Comment: yeah but the is more than one choice !

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible.. i would use two tables one for questions and another for choices. And make a question id as a foreign key of choices table. Use join query to fetch the questions and choices

Comment: can you give me an example of using join in this case !

Comment: see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969170/how-to-use-foreign-key-when-querying-from-two-tables] I hope it will help.